# Kendo Grid: Onchange event is not triggering

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I'm trying to implement some functionality in "onchange" of text box in telerik kendo grid. But it is not firing in change; instead it's firing on onBlur.

The code is here. [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/Okize/5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used "onkeyup" event. It works :)

Answer (score 0):

To track the changes in the editors inside the column templates you should use different approach. Please check the example below:

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [ {
      field: "name",
      template: kendo.template($("#name-template").html())
    }],
    dataSource: {
      data: [ {id: 1,  name: "Jane Doe" }, {id: 2, name: "John Doe" } ],
      //schema is required for enabling valid CRUD operations
      schema: {
        model: {
          id: "id",
          fields: {
            id: {type: "number"},
            name: {type: "string"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

  grid.table.on("change", "input", function(e) {
    alert("change");

    //optionally update the underlying model:
    var editor = $(this);
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(editor.closest("tr"));
    dataItem.set("name", editor.val());
  });
```

Another option is to use the MVVM approach shown in the following demo:

- http://dojo.telerik.com/Utino

Answer (score 0):

You should try "[onkeypress](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)" event. It will work as per your requirement.